# How long does it take for Google Webmaster Tools to notice links that have been removed?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

In order to comply better with Google's guidelines, we've gone to a lot of effort to remove links to our website. However, sites that no longer link to us still show up in our Google Webmaster Tools. These links were removed over a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

The links will be there until the crawler will not reach those pages where links were.

Comment: Is there a way I can determine that?

Comment: I guess there is no way to affect the Google crawler work.